# Regex subbing in Python leads to ASCII characters appearing

Tags: python, regex, string

I am trying to use regex to replace some issues in some text.

Strings look like this:

`a = "Here is a shortString with various issuesWith spacing"`

My regex looks like this right now:
`new_string = re.sub("[a-z][A-Z]", "\1 \2", a)`.

This takes those places with missing spaces (there is always a capital letter after a lowercase letter), and adds a space.

Unfortunately, the output looks like this:

`Here is a shor\x01 \x02tring with various issue\x01 \x02ith spacing`

I want it to look like this:

`b = "Here is a short String with various issues With spacing"`

It seems that the regex is properly matching the correct instances of things I want to change, but there is something wrong with my substitution. I thought `\1 \2` meant replace with the first part of the regex, add a space, and then add the second matched item. But for some reason I get something else?

Comment: You need raw strings. Add `r` in front of both string declarations. `r"[a-z][A-Z]", r"\1 \2"`.

Comment: You did not set the capturing groups, use `"([a-z])([A-Z])"`. And use `r'\1 \2'`

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> a = "Here is a shortString with various issuesWith spacing"
>>> re.sub("([a-z])([A-Z])", r"\1 \2", a)
'Here is a short String with various issues With spacing'
```

capturing group and backslash escaping was missing.

you can go even further:

```
>>> a = "Here is a shortString with various issuesWith spacing"
>>> re.sub('([a-z])([A-Z])', r'\1 \2', a).lower().capitalize()
'Here is a short string with various issues with spacing'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define capturing groups, and use raw string literals:

```
import re
a = "Here is a shortString with various issuesWith spacing"
new_string = re.sub(r"([a-z])([A-Z])", r"\1 \2", a)
print(new_string)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/CoE8xR).

Note that without the `r''` prefix Python interpreted the `\1` and `\2` as characters rather than as backreferences since the `\` was parsed as part of an escape sequence. In raw string literals, `\` is parsed as a literal backslash.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a try like this:

```
>>>> import re
>>>> a = "Here is a shortString with various issuesWith spacing"
>>>> re.sub(r"(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])", " ", a)
>>>> Here is a short String with various issues With spacing
```